# Import Chrome bookmarks to Safari under iOS

Tags: ios, google-chrome, mobile-safari, bookmarks

I just wanted to know if it is possible to import Chrome bookmarks into Safari on iOS?

I’m using Safari on my iPhone but I am using Chrome for work. And now I just want to have all my bookmarks Chrome also in Safari, without using my computer to export the bookmarks and then manually import it on my Mac.

Comment: Where precisely are your chrome bookmarks stored? I can't believe that there is no export feature that wouldn't save them to the Files app and then get them over to Safari. or are you simply asking if Apple wrote an import or chrome wrote an export. Google surely doesn't want you to leave their browser, so I get they won't prioritize that. Apple also might also not add that feature, but surely some developer has worked on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is currently not possible to do this without a computer.

Comment: 's answer is spot on - worth pointin\g out that iCloud supports bookmark synching, so though you do need to export the chrome bookmarks and import them into Safari on your Mac, you then are done, as this will synch with all devices linked through the same Apple ID, so you needn't do the connect your iPhone to your Mac, synch via iTunes shuffle.

Comment: It also relies on iCloud syncing working to iOS, which it sometimes does.

Answer (score -1):

Very basic functionality like this doesn’t exist at apple because they want you to buy a mac.  It’s moves like this that will keep them behind the competition as the world advances with open source software.

Comment: That's an interesting opinion. Most of the people covering Apple professionally  lament that Apple is pushing iOS over Mac and you seem to be saying the opposite. Perhaps we should take these discussions to [chat] unless you can edit your answer to address the question at hand directly? I can't believe no one has an app or process to do this. I would start with Pythonista to process the file and then inject them if I were assigned this task to work. I don't think it's impossible at all.